# How to generate features from GeoXML MapServer response in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, gis, mapserver, openlayers-5

Could anyone explain to me the good way to initialize a vector layer using a response from a MapServer?

Here is the way i do:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: name,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        wrapX: false,
        url: function (extent) {
            return data.map_server_adress + 
            "&typename=" + name +
            "&srs=" + data.projection +
            "&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&BBOX="+ extent.join(',');
        },
        format: new ol.format.GML(),
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
})
```

And it seems to work since i get this kind of responses from the server:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection>
    <gml:boundedBy>
      <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:27572">
        <gml:coordinates>915095.490151,2081613.946304 915547.647404,2082070.940534</gml:coordinates>
      </gml:Box>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
      <ms:parcelles_wfs fid="parcelles_wfs.10583768">
        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:27572">
                <gml:coordinates>915289.953312,2081613.946304 915330.053226,2081669.612361</gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Box>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <ms:msGeometry>
        <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:27572">
          <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
            <gml:LinearRing>
              <gml:coordinates>915315.110225,2081613.946304 915307.324782,2081627.632231 915301.500411,2081637.931837 915289.953312,2081658.351753 915303.878919,2081667.360430 915307.332797,2081669.612361 915330.053226,2081628.008577 915315.110225,2081613.946304 </gml:coordinates>
            </gml:LinearRing>
          </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        </gml:Polygon>
        </ms:msGeometry>
        <ms:ogc_fid>10583768</ms:ogc_fid>
      </ms:parcelles_wfs>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

But then when i try to get features from the source of the layer i just get an empty array. I tried to print the source and features informations above seems to be in a member named nullGeometryFeatures_. I guess OpenLayers isn't able to build the feature's geometry but can't understand why?

**EDIT** :
Thanks to Mike's answer i realised the server i use was sending GML2 data while OpenLayers default expected format is GML3. So if your data looks like [that](http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=continents&MAXFEATURES=1&OUTPUTFORMAT=gml2) instead of [that](http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=continents&MAXFEATURES=1&OUTPUTFORMAT=gml3), you just have to change `new ol.format.GML()` to `new ol.format.GML2()` !

Comment: Have you tried `format: new ol.format.WFS()`

Comment: @Mike Yes I tried but got the same problem, everything is pushed into nullGeometryFeatures_

Comment: It seems like non-standard GML.  OpenLayers supports Simplified Features http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlsfProfile/1.0.0/gmlsf.xsd where the coordinates should be specified by <gml:posList>.not by <gml:coordinates>

Comment: Thanks ! you're right ! OpenLayers seems to use GML3 standard while the server I request return GML2 formated xml as you can see here : http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=continents&MAXFEATURES=1&OUTPUTFORMAT=gml2

Comment: Unfortunatly i don't have the hand on this server so i'll try to solve this compatibility issue and add an answer to this post !

Comment: OpenLayers also has `format.GML2` but I'm not sure how much it supports

Comment: Great thanks ! GML2 format solved my problem, I did not know it exists. Should I add an answer to the post for better visibility ?